# Problem after adding external dependencies in IntelliJ

Tags: xml, kotlin, dependencies, korge

I'm starting a project using the KorGE library, and I would like to use Retrofit as XML parser.
So I try to follow [this guide](https://medium.com/@Mak95/parsing-xml-data-via-retrofit-2-x-using-kotlin-3ce007d00cf8), which seems fine, but I just poorly get stuck by adding the dependencies in the first step.

I already have the KorGE libraries included (I started from the template):

```
dependencies {
    classpath("com.soywiz.korlibs.korge.plugins:korge-gradle-plugin:$korgePluginVersion")
    classpath("com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock:1.6.1")
}
```

But when I try to includes the following dependencies, everything turns to hell when I load gradle changes (I guess this is the way I should declare them?):

```
classpath("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.4.0")
classpath("com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:2.4.0")
```

In the guide it seems that this dependencies are part of APIs, but I did not found anything different about declaration on the net. If I just copy-past it obviously doesn't work.

The errors I get after loading gradle changes:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderScope@a2e5ac5 must be locked before it can be used to compute a classpath!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: project.classLoaderScope must be locked before querying the project schema
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help guys, and sorry for my noobiness.

Comment: It may be related to this issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4823. I had the same effect because I use kotlin dsl with windows, many app modules in nested directories and with enabled `org.gradle.configureondemand=true` in main `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 6):

Removing `org.gradle.configureondemand=true` in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution worked for me**

I was also facing this issue, and I didn't find a solution. This below solution worked for me.

**Cause:**

I was using kotlin build.gradle. And I was using below

`classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")`

Where `kotlinVersion` was in another class & it was imported like

`import DependenciesVersions.kotlinVersion`
Which was causing issue.

**Solution:**

Remove import line from `build.gradle.kts`
Use your version like this

`classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${DependenciesVersions.kotlinVersion}")`

And now sync project, it will work.